# Sorting by alphabetical order

Tags: ocaml

I would like to create a function which will add a registration number plus a certain negative time. Here is an example :

```
# enter_car "DEF456" (−4) [("ABC13", −2); ("GHI789", −3)];;
− : (string∗int) list = [("ABC13", −2); ("DEF456" , −4); ("GHI789", −3)]
```

I am pretty sure I am able to add `("DEF456", -4)` to the list. The problem is the list has to be sorted by alphabetical order. How can I sort the list in alphabetical order according to the registration number?

Comment: Have you checked the API reference, if there might be some useful ready-made function you can use there? https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

Comment: @glennsl I can see the sort function, but I am not sure how to use it in my context

Comment: You need to supply a function that compares two tuples and tells what order they should go in. This is standard for almost all languages, since there are many possible desired orders.

Comment: Another hint: the `String` module has a function to compare two string that happen to fit the specification `List.sort` asks for.

Comment: Can you have duplicate reg numbers? If not then you should look at a set.

Comment: @glennsl `sort (fun (x, _) (y, _) -> if x < y then -1 else 1) my_list;;` Do you think it is fine?

Comment: your comparison function will say that `"x"` is not equal to `"x"` so it is broken. Hint, it never returns `0`. Hint, use `String.compare` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works perfectly!

```
let enter_car registration_num time current_list = 
        let new_list = (registration_num, time)::current_list in 
        sort (fun (x, _) (y, _) -> String.compare x y) new_list;;
```